# Unable to insert data into MySQL using php form, database is connected

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a school assignment and a particular page I'm working on requires me to enter data into MySQL using php. The database is connected and I've referred to my codes from a previous class which is almost the same, apart from the variable names. I've tried many ways but somehow I can't get data to be inserted. Unable to work on my retrieval page unless this is up and running.. Please help!

```
<p class="lead">
<?php


  $submitted = isset($_POST['formSubmitted']);

  if ($submitted) {

        if (!empty($_POST['BookingDate'])) {
            $BookingDate=$_POST['BookingDate'];
        } else {
            $BookingDate=NULL;
            echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to choose your date of booking!</font><p>';
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['CustName'])) {
            $CustName=$_POST['CustName'];
        } else {
            $CustName=NULL;
            echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter your Name!</font><p>';
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['CustContact'])) {
            $CustContact=$_POST['CustContact'];
        } else {
            $CustContact=NULL;
            echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter your contact number!</font><p>';
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['TableType'])) {
            $TableType=$_POST['TableType'];
        } else {
            $TableType=NULL;
            echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to choose your table type!</font><p>';
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['TableLocation'])) {
            $TableLocation=$_POST['TableLocation'];
        } else {
            $TableLocation=NULL;
            echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to choose your table location!</font><p>';
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['ICNumber'])) {
            $IcNumber=$_POST['ICNumber'];
        } else {
            $ICNumber=NULL;
            echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter your IC Number!</font><p>';
        }

  if ($BookingDate && $CustName && $CustContact && $TableType && $TableLocation && $ICNumber) {
      echo '<h2><font color="green">Booking information has been entered successfully!</font></h2></p>';

      $BookingDate=$_POST['BookingDate'];
      $CustName=$_POST['CustName'];
      $CustContact=$_POST['CustContact'];
      $TableType=$_POST['TableType'];
      $TableLocation=$_POST['TableLocation'];
      $ICNumber=$_POST['ICNumber'];


      echo "The following details have been entered: </br>";
      echo '<ol>';
      echo "<li>Date: $BookingDate </br>";
      echo "<li>Name: $CustName </br>";
      echo "<li>Contact: $CustContact </br>";
      echo "<li>Table Type: $TableType </br>";
      echo "<li>Table Location: $TableLocation </br>";
      echo "<li>IC Number: $ICNumber </br>";
      echo '<ul></br></br>';

    $BookingDate = new DateTime;      
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", null, "kiewcRMAD");
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `kiewcRMAD`.`TableBooking` (`BookingDate`, `CustName`, `CustContact`, `TableType`, `TableLocation`, `ICNumber`) VALUES ('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssisss', $BookingDate, $CustName, $CustContact, $TableType, $TableLocation, $ICNumber);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->close();



    }
  }



  ?>


<fieldset>
  <legend> Enter Booking Information in the form below:</legend>


  <p>
  <b>Date of Booking:</b>
  <input type="text" name="BookingDate" size="30" value="<?php if (isset ($_POST['BookingDate']))echo $BookingDate;?>"/>
  </p>



  <p>
  <b>Name:</b>
  <input type="text" name="CustName" size="30" maxlength="20" value="<?php if (isset ($_POST['CustName']))echo $CustName;?>"/>

  </p>

  <p>
  <b>Contact:</b>
  <input type="number" name="CustContact" size="15" maxlength="8" value="<?php if (isset ($_POST['CustContact']))echo $CustContact;?>"/>
  </p>

  <p>
  <b>Table Type:</b>
  <SELECT size="1" name="TableType">
    <OPTION value="">--Select--</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="Standing Table"<?php if ((isset ($_POST['TableType'])) && ($_POST['TableType'] == "Standing Table")) echo "selected='selected'";?>>Standing Table</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="Single Sofa" <?php if ((isset ($_POST['TableType'])) && ($_POST['TableType'] == "Single Sofa")) echo "selected='selected'";?>>Single Sofa</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="Double Sofa"<?php if ((isset ($_POST['TableType'])) && ($_POST['TableType'] == "Double Sofa")) echo "selected='selected'";?>>Double Sofa</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="VIP Table"<?php if ((isset ($_POST['TableType'])) && ($_POST['TableType'] == "VIP Table")) echo "selected='selected'";?>>VIP Table</OPTION>
  </SELECT>
  </p>


  <p>

  <b>Table Location:</b>
  <input type="radio" name="TableLocation" value="King's Lounge" <?php if ((isset ($_POST['TableLocation'])) && ($_POST['TableLocation'] == "King's Lounge")) echo "checked'";?>/> King's Lounge 
  <input type="radio" name="TableLocation" value="Queen's Loft" <?php if ((isset ($_POST['TableLocation'])) && ($_POST['TableLocation'] == "Queen's Loft")) echo "checked'";?>/> Queen's Loft

  </p>

  <p>
  <b>IC Number:</b>
  <input type="text" name="ICNumber" size="15" maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset ($_POST['ICNumber']))echo $ICNumber;?>"/>
  </p>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="hidden" name="formSubmitted" value="TRUE" />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
  <input type="reset" value="Reset" />


</form>
```

Comment: You should add error handling to your database calls.

Comment: Simple, remove the quotes in `('?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')` - `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` would have told you.

Comment: Do you get error mssg(s)...??

Answer (score 2):

Since I'm not sure if you're getting any notifications for messages left in the comments area (or aware of that section), am submitting the following as an actual answer.
*Let's see if you do get a notification for it.*

You're using quotes around each `?` placeholder, which in turn is acting as passing a literal string instead of using for its intended purpose, a placeholder.

Remove the quotes `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Example from that page:

```
/* Prepared statement, stage 1: prepare */
if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Having used error checking such as, and in place of `$stmt->execute();`

```
if(!$stmt->execute()){
  trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

would have signaled and shown you the syntax error.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: Not sure the OP is aware of the answer section either ;-)

Comment: @jeroen Time will tell, I guess ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, will give that a go. It's the last day of Chinese New Year here so I haven't been online.
- Yes, I do get notifications for the comments.
- Also, notifications for answers

Comment: Hello @Charlene and Happy Chinese New Year by the way! Did my answer provide you with a solution?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey Fred, tried removing the quotes around the ? placeholder and it's still the same - no errors, but data is still not inserting.

Comment: @Charlene Hey Charlene. Try replacing `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` if you haven't already, which I posted in my answer and see if anything comes of it. Check your column types and use error reporting as outlined at the bottom in my answer.

Comment: @Charlene Another thing. Try replacing `if ($submitted) {` with `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` - Using conditional statements based on hidden inputs shouldn't be relied upon. Also changing `INSERT INTO `kiewcRMAD`.`TableBooking`` with `INSERT INTO TableBooking` since you're already declaring the `kiewcRMAD` database in your db connection.